# Removing google analytics

Tags: javascript

I want to test website performance, comparing with vs without gtag.js / google annalytics. I block-commented as showing here:

```
    <!-- <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-5******-1"></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date()); gtag('config', 'UA-5******-1');
    </script> -->
```

But Lighthouse and other similar checks still report as though the scripts are still running:
i.e.
Remove unused JavaScript to reduce bytes consumed by network activity. Learn more.

```
URL
Transfer Size
Potential Savings
/gtm.js?id=GTM-K796DLL(www.googletagmanager.com)
63.9 KiB
30.1 KiB
```

Comment: Have you tried just deleting it for the test

Comment: Maybe your server has cache turned on? Some services have it even without telling their clients. Normally you should be able to empty the cache from your cpanel/admin panel or from your admin panel if you use Wordpress with a plugin, for example.